# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: maven

[image]

When I try importing the previously developed maven project. It is showing this error. I tried reimporting and running still it is showing the same error. Thanks in advance. any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Please try first on plain command line to build your project....

Comment: Have the same issue, building in command line work. It's only in eclipse I have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar error earlier, try updating the parent to latest version in pom.xml file and build again.